# How to store a reference to a login query?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

Say I have some login form and when a user logs in I only want to show certain things but for security purpuses I don't want to show the Identification of the user in my query, for example "www.MySite.com/SomeData?KeyToAccessData=SECRET_KEY"

there I would obviously not want the key to show so that people can log from that person's account so ; how would I keep a reference to the person's ID to remember him?

Comment: you didn't get my question, the form itself is complete, but once you are done and you logged in, I need to remember who is the user and if he has rights to open certain data, only show him what he's allowed to see basically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you have not to reinvent the wheel, there is already ASP.Net Identity that doing all stuffs about authentification for you,

ASP.NET Identity : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity

ASP.Net Identity Core : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Thank you I'll check it out